# Deadlock during trigger with stored procedure executions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have triggers on two tables. Inside the trigger, there is a stored procedure  execution and then an update statement. Both tables' trigger refers to same stored procedure and update statement.

However, not always but few times I am getting deadlock error as following.

I tried to understand deadlock, but could not figure out what is wrong as I am new with handling the deadlock issue.

**EDIT:**

The purpose of executing store procedure in trigger is to update "Outstanding" of customer being transacted. There are around 15 tables in database which holds various types of transactions for customers. e.g receipt, sales, payment, purchase etc. are the tables. What I am trying to archive is, if transaction is being recorded in any of these tables, use trigger to calculate customer outstanding. Stored procedure used inside the trigger checks all transactions in all 15 tables and return outstanding amount, and then next statement in trigger use this value to update record of that particular customer in table customermaster.

In short: stored procedure looks into all 15 tables for transactions of particular customer and returns float value.

Use trigger in all 15 tables to execute this stored procedure to get outstanding value and update same in customermaster table after each transaction in these 15 tables.

How can I resolve this deadlock?

```
deadlock-list
 deadlock victim=process269c4decca8


  process-list
  
  
  
   
   process id=process269c4decca8 taskpriority=0 logused=436 waitresource=PAGE: 7:1:1066036  waittime=4697 ownerId=84823833 transactionname=INSERT lasttranstarted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.623 XDES=0x26ab7dc9c90 lockMode=S schedulerid=2 kpid=10976 status=suspended spid=564 sbid=0 ecid=4 priority=0 trancount=0 lastbatchstarted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.620 lastbatchcompleted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.630 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.630 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=COLLECTION_S01 hostpid=8596 isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=84823833 currentdb=7 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671219744 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=demo.dbo.SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID line=14 stmtstart=796 stmtend=19944 sqlhandle=0x03000700e5c546737bebfe00f9ab000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Select Round(SUM(B.Debit),1) - Round(SUM(B.Credit),1) as Outstanding from
(
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Debit),0) as 'Debit',ISNULL(SUM(Credit),0)  as 'Credit' from  
(
--declare @ledgerid as float = 5492
Select Sum(Cast(CNamount as Decimal(28,2))) as Debit,0 as Credit
From ServiceStock as SS Left Join demouniversal.dbo.DistributorMaster D on (SS.SendDistributorID = D.DistributorID) Left Join ExpenseLedgerDetails ED on D.DistributorID= ED.DistributorID 
Where ED.LedgerID=@ledgerid 
UNION ALL
Select 0 as Debit,Sum(Cast((P.BilledQty * P.UnitNLC) as Decimal(28,2))) as Credit
From pur_vir_inw_det P left join pur_vir_inw_mst V on P.VPINo = V.VPINo left join demouniversal.dbo.DistributorMaster D on (V.CompanyID = D.DistributorID) Left Join ExpenseLedgerDetails ED on D.DistributorID= ED.DistributorID 
Where ED.LedgerID=@ledgerid
Union all
Select 0 as Debit,Sum(IsNull(Freight,0) + IsNull(SGSTAmt,0) + IsNull(CGSTAmt,0) - ISNULL(V.Discount,0)) as Credit
From pur_vir_inw_mst V  
left join demouniv     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=74 stmtend=352 sqlhandle=0x010008006b50070c20fc71396b02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EXEC demo.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID] @ledgerid = 4955, @customerid = 4955, @ResultValue2= @ResultValue4 outpu     
     frame procname=demouniversal.dbo.SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database line=59 stmtstart=5272 stmtend=5708 sqlhandle=0x0300080053f6d95222360101f9ab000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
insert into @temp exec ('declare @ResultValue4 decimal (16,2) EXEC '+@db+'.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID] @ledgerid = '+@LedgerID+', @customerid = '+@cust_id_T+', @ResultValue2= @ResultValue4 output'     
     frame procname=demo.dbo.Update_OS_SP_ExpJournal line=35 stmtstart=3816 stmtend=4062 sqlhandle=0x03000700aa4e4c550e7f0101f9ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EXEC demouniversal.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database] null, @in_FromLedgerId, @return_status outpu     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=204 stmtend=586 sqlhandle=0x02000000c012c63838e02bd6dca13d67f09290998bcb26fd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=412 sqlhandle=0x0200000020cd1b370590d65507e440a267d97d962bda59710000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
INSERT INTO demo.dbo.ExpenseJournal (EmployeeID,TransactionDate,FromLedger,ToLedger,Amount,Remarks,Type,RefName,Dflag,ID) VALUES (1658,'2020-07-15',4955,2936,350000,'being cash deposite',1,'',0,44520)    
   
   
   
   
   process id=process269e701e4e8 taskpriority=0 logused=1256 waitresource=PAGE: 7:1:541270  waittime=4734 ownerId=84826380 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.753 XDES=0x26a01d2c490 lockMode=S schedulerid=1 kpid=2724 status=suspended spid=303 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2020-07-17T14:09:41.200 lastbatchcompleted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.750 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.750 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=CASH_S05 hostpid=4268 loginname=ims isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=84826380 currentdb=8 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671219744 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=3096 sqlhandle=0x0200000018ac5a254532fb705262b54a8e0a4b9689bc29ac0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=demouniversal.dbo.SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database line=41 stmtstart=4356 stmtend=4408 sqlhandle=0x0300080053f6d95222360101f9ab000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
INSERT INTO @t1 exec (@sql     
     frame procname=demo.dbo.Update_OS_SP_Receipt line=16 stmtstart=1486 stmtend=1728 sqlhandle=0x03000700a908b74c60cc2e01f9ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EXEC demouniversal.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database] @in_customerId, NULL, @return_status Outpu     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=696 stmtend=1770 sqlhandle=0x02000000a1f53a36574a899cbd5dca29c8d01e26bb8988860000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=1370 sqlhandle=0x020000003f4b62186ff8b7e2ab4637ce6fb107b9df1659cc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
Insert into Receipt (StoreID,ReceiptNo,Date,RTime,InvoiceNo,Cashier,SalesEx,CustomerID,DCustomerID,DCustomerName,DMobile,DPhone,DAddress,DCity,BCustomerName,BMobile,BPhone,BAddress,BCity,BDOB,PaymentMode,Amount,IsAdvancedReceipt,CODID,FromInvOrCOD,AmountExclVAT,UpdatedDate,RecTallyflag,Remarks) values ('S05','RC299970','2020-07-17',CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),'IV478531',845,480,350986,350986,'ABC XYZ','9999999999','9999999999','Test',1102,'ABC XYZ','9999999999','9999999999','Test',1102,'1996-12-14',0,5891,0,-1,1,0,CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 120),0,'')    
   
   
   
   
   
   process id=process26a5ae8c108 taskpriority=0 logused=10000 waittime=4692 schedulerid=6 kpid=10760 status=suspended spid=564 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.620 lastbatchcompleted=2020-07-17T14:09:40.630 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.630 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=COLLECTION_S01 hostpid=8596 loginname=ims isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=84823833 currentdb=7 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671219744 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=demo.dbo.SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID line=14 stmtstart=796 stmtend=19944 sqlhandle=0x03000700e5c546737bebfe00f9ab000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Select Round(SUM(B.Debit),1) - Round(SUM(B.Credit),1) as Outstanding from
(
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Debit),0) as 'Debit',ISNULL(SUM(Credit),0)  as 'Credit' from  
(
--declare @ledgerid as float = 5492
Select Sum(Cast(CNamount as Decimal(28,2))) as Debit,0 as Credit
From ServiceStock as SS Left Join demouniversal.dbo.DistributorMaster D on (SS.SendDistributorID = D.DistributorID) Left Join ExpenseLedgerDetails ED on D.DistributorID= ED.DistributorID 
Where ED.LedgerID=@ledgerid 
UNION ALL
Select 0 as Debit,Sum(Cast((P.BilledQty * P.UnitNLC) as Decimal(28,2))) as Credit
From pur_vir_inw_det P left join pur_vir_inw_mst V on P.VPINo = V.VPINo left join demouniversal.dbo.DistributorMaster D on (V.CompanyID = D.DistributorID) Left Join ExpenseLedgerDetails ED on D.DistributorID= ED.DistributorID 
Where ED.LedgerID=@ledgerid
Union all
Select 0 as Debit,Sum(IsNull(Freight,0) + IsNull(SGSTAmt,0) + IsNull(CGSTAmt,0) - ISNULL(V.Discount,0)) as Credit
From pur_vir_inw_mst V  
left join demouniv     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=74 stmtend=352 sqlhandle=0x010008006b50070c20fc71396b02000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EXEC demo.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID] @ledgerid = 4955, @customerid = 4955, @ResultValue2= @ResultValue4 outpu     
     frame procname=demouniversal.dbo.SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database line=59 stmtstart=5272 stmtend=5708 sqlhandle=0x0300080053f6d95222360101f9ab000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
insert into @temp exec ('declare @ResultValue4 decimal (16,2) EXEC '+@db+'.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_LedgerID] @ledgerid = '+@LedgerID+', @customerid = '+@cust_id_T+', @ResultValue2= @ResultValue4 output'     
     frame procname=demo.dbo.Update_OS_SP_ExpJournal line=35 stmtstart=3816 stmtend=4062 sqlhandle=0x03000700aa4e4c550e7f0101f9ab000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
EXEC demouniversal.[dbo].[SP_GET_Outstanding_on_CustomerID_For_All_database] null, @in_FromLedgerId, @return_status outpu     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=204 stmtend=586 sqlhandle=0x02000000c012c63838e02bd6dca13d67f09290998bcb26fd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=412 sqlhandle=0x0200000020cd1b370590d65507e440a267d97d962bda59710000000000000000000000000000000000000000
unknown     
    inputbuf
INSERT INTO demo.dbo.ExpenseJournal (EmployeeID,TransactionDate,FromLedger,ToLedger,Amount,Remarks,Type,RefName,Dflag,ID) VALUES (1658,'2020-07-15',4955,2936,350000,'being cash deposite',1,'',0,44520)    
  
  
  
  
  
  resource-list
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=1066036 dbid=7 subresource=FULL objectname=demo.dbo.receipt id=lock26b09d53500 mode=IX associatedObjectId=72057594114211840
    owner-list
     owner id=process269e701e4e8 mode=IX
    
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process269c4decca8 mode=S requestType=wait
   pagelock fileid=1 pageid=541270 dbid=7 subresource=FULL objectname=demo.dbo.ExpenseLedgerDetails id=lock2694e2aa100 mode=SIX associatedObjectId=72057594121224192
    
    
    owner-list
     owner id=process26a5ae8c108 mode=SIX
    
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process269e701e4e8 mode=S requestType=wait
   exchangeEvent id=Pipe26aaaf70b80 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=214
    
    owner-list
     owner id=process269c4decca8
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process26a5ae8c108
```

Comment: The fact that you are calling a Stored Procedure from a Trigger sounds like a design flaw unto itself. A Trigger should have as minimal impact as possible. Clearly it is not minimal if it's causing/receiving deadlocks. Seems the real solution here is to reconsider your design.

Comment: I totally agree with @Larnu - but if procedures can cause deadlocks in triggers, they can cause deadlocks without triggers too, esp inside transactions. Least what you should do is to redesign your procedures transaction-safe - if you for example query some table and write same table afterwards, then you should use `updlock` hint for querying etc.

Comment: i have edited main question, explaining why I am using store procedure in trigger.Hope I am able to explain the situation.

Comment: The challenge with triggers calling SPs is exactly what you're running in to--deadlocks/locking. My suspicion is that your SP is trying to access a record that your trigger has a lock on. If there is no way around this--which happens--you can try adding the `WITH ( NOLOCK )` hint to any tables referenced in your SP that your trigger may be holding a lock on.